# rospack cache per workspace?

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rospack cache is currently build user-wide. I often switch between workspaces that contain different sets of packages or the same package at different locations.

I heavily rely on tab-completion. Rospack does everything correctly here, i.e. I've never seen it switch to a wrong package location. However, when I switch the workspace and then observe a now new to rospack package again roscd (caused by rospack I assume) hangs until I either put in the package manually or it has found it.

Is there any way to preserve the rospack cache for a specific workspace?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108486/rospack-cache-per-workspace?/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, that is currently not possible.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-09**:
Unfortunately that's what I thought.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-09**:
`rospack` could use an environment specific cache file. But I guess it would take quite some effort to implement.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-09**:
So I checked out the sources. Would it be sufficient to (maybe optionally) use $ROS_WORKSPACE to determine the path to put the cache files? roscd, etc. should just use rospack then, right? If you think that is feasible I'd be willing to provide a patch.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-10**:
$ROS_WORKSPACE is not an "official" variable of ROS. It is only defined and used by some of the tools. The cache should be ROS_PACKAGE_PATH specific. The cache file(s) should stay in the same location as they are currently (`~/.ros/`). Yes, commands like roscd use rospack.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-10**:
OK, in that case it's not trivial to do unfortunately.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-11**:
Let me give this one more shot: What do you think about naming the files: rospack_cache_MD5SUM_OF_$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? This would lead to package path specific caches nicely hidden in ~/.ros. After thinking about this for a while it doesn't seem to be that hacky to me any more.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-11**:
Yes, that would be good.